# Is it possible to trigger an event when a embedded youtube video is clicked?

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, triggers, youtube-api

I have a `<iframe>` container with an `id="youtube-frame-1"`
And in the javascript trying to trigger an event when a the youtube embedded video is being clicked, like this

```
$("#youtube-iframe-1").click(function(event) {
  if (x.addEventListener) {                    // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
    x.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  } else if (x.attachEvent) {                  // For IE 8 and earlier versions
    x.attachEvent("onclick", myFunction);
  }
});


function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}
```

but nothing pops up why`?

Comment: Have you tried using [iframe Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events)?

Comment: which event doesn't seem to have list of parameter?